# How can you put your LIMIT inside a subquery in JPQL?

Tags: java, jpql

Are queries like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   users
   ORDER  BY id
   LIMIT  3
   OFFSET 3
   ) sub
ORDER  BY id DESC;
```

translatable into JPQL? I'm not sure since `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, which are not supported directly inside a JPQL string, are placed inside a subquery. The problem with `setMaxResults()` and `setFirstResult()` is that the associated SQL keywords are going to be appended to the outermost query whatever you do, it is not customizable

My `LIMIT`, `OFFSET` and `GROUP BY` values are actually dynamic and represent pagination parameters passed in an HTTP request. I know `OFFSET` is not very good for pagination, but even if you replace it with `WHERE`, you're still left with `LIMIT` that should still be inside a subquery

**How do I turn that SQL into JPQL?**

P.S.: In case you're wondering why I need `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` *inside* a subquery, you may visit [this page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/327892/can-you-make-postgres-execute-order-by-after-offset-and-limit)

**UPD:** Here's ChatGPT-4's suggestion

```java
// Assuming you have an EntityManager named 'entityManager'

int limit = 3;
int offset = 3;
String jpql = "SELECT u FROM User u ORDER BY u.id";

TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, User.class);
query.setMaxResults(limit);
query.setFirstResult(offset);

List<User> users = query.getResultList();

// If you want to reverse the order of the returned list
Collections.reverse(users);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution you have above would work.
If not, then I would try this. Assuming you have a User.java class, and a SessionFactory, I believe you can create a method like this:

```java
    public List<User> fetchUsersWithOffsetAndLimit(SessionFactory session, int offset, int limit) {
     List<User> userList = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery(From User)
       .setFirstResult(offset)
       .setMaxResults(limit)
       .list();

     List<User> usersSortedByOrderIdDesc = new ArrayList<>();

     for (int i = userList.size(); i > 0; i--) {
      usersSortedByOrderIdDesc.add(userList.get(i));
     }
    
    return usersSortedByOrderIdDesc;
    }

// SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtils.getLocSessionFactory();
// Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

I added the SessionFactory that can be called within the parameter. It can be added within the method if you are not passing it inside the method call.

There may be a more efficient way of doing it but I think this will work.

Comment: The original query applies an additional `ORDER BY` *after* `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

Comment: I have modified my response.